# Can't log in to Stack Overflow with Google

Tags: support, login, google-openid

I log into Stack Exchange sites using my Google details.  For the last few days I can't log in to the main Stack Overflow.  As you can see I'm successfully able to log in to Meta, and I can log in to all the other sites I've tried (Server fault, Photography).

But on the main Stack Overflow, if I click "log in" I'm redirected to the main page but still not logged in.

For info I've watched the process in Firebug; everything looks reasonable, it does a POST to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login/global

which results in the following response:

```
{"Message":"Welcome back <a href=\"/users/382166/asc99c\">asc99c</a>, you've been logged in."}
```

But I haven't!

Comment: Have you tried logging in with a new profile? See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for how to start the profile manager.

Comment: Just tried resetting Firefox (never seen that feature before!) but I still can't log in

Comment: It is definitely in that area though, I can log in with Chrome just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this exact same issue 2 years after you.  I think the cookies get corrupted.

I solved it by deleting my cookies for all Stack Exchange sites.

In Chrome:

1. Go to your `Settings`
2. Click `Show advanced settings...`
3. Under the `Privacy` header, click the `Content Settings...` button
4. Under the `Cookies` header, click the `All cookies and site data...` button
5. Filter (`Search`) with the word *stack*
6. For every site that has `# cookies`, click the delete `X` on the right side

   - You can ignore the ones that only say `Local Storage`
7. Go to your Stack Exchange site and login!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the the same problems, just delete entire browsing history from your browser and problem will be solved.